# Is there a way to add to a variable every time an if statement is true

Tags: python, if-statement

```
if a == tru:
    correct += 1
    qq = str(q)
    aa = str(a)
    print("you answered correctly! \n" + qq + " does equal " + aa)
    print()
```

What I want to do is every time a equals tru, the variable correct adds 1. I tried using a while loop, but I think I set it up wrong because then correct remained zero. Is there any way to fix this?

Edit:

```
import random
u = input("how many questions?\n")
y = int(u)
for x in range(y):
  s = random.randint(1,12)
  r = random.randint(1,12)
  q = (str(s) + " * " + str(r))
  a = int(input(q + "="))
  tru = (s*r)
  correct = 0
  if a == tru:
    correct += 1
    qq = str(q)
    aa = str(a)
    print("you answered correctly! \n" + qq + " does equal " + aa)
    print( )

  elif a != tru:
    qq = str(q)
    aa = str(a)
    truu = str(tru)
    print("sorry, " + qq + " does not equal " + aa)
    print(qq + " equals " + truu)
    print( )

  o = str(l)
  print("You got "+ o +" out of "+ u)
```

This will add more context. The code asks how many questions you want, then gives you basic multiplication questions and tells you whether it is correct. I want to add a message that says "you got ___ out of ___" at the end. Please tell me if you have any other suggestions on how to do this.

Edit 2:
I had correct=0 in a for loop, meaning every time it looped correct was reset. Whoops. Anyway, if you come across this and want to use it to help teach basic multiplication, just move the correct=0 out of the for loop and it should work.

Comment: what's that last print() for?

Also, the `correct +=1` is correct. How are you determining that correct remains zero? Does the print work correctly?

Comment: Can you show more of the code or explain the meaning/context of these variables?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO ! could you also post the remaining part of the code. Because the information in the code sample provided above, is not enough to debug the error. Thanks

Comment: I don't see `correct` being stored anywhere outside of this scope.

Comment: It is also not clear where the input `q` and `a` comes from? And perhaps you rather mean 'every time a equals q' ??

Comment: Responding to all the comments:
The last print is start a new line so it looks nicer, \n wouldn't work in this scenario. When I run the program, right now no matter how many I get correct It always says I got one right. I have added the rest of the code and an explanation of what it is meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say exactly what could be going wrong given the code you've submitted, but as long as `correct` is stored outside your loop, incrementing it in this way should work just fine. Below is a working example that demonstrates this.

```py
test = [[True, "Question 1"], [False, "Question 2"], [True, "Question 3"]]
correct = 0

for a, q in test:
    if a:
        correct += 1
        print("You answered correctly!")
        print(f"{q} does equal {a}")
    else:
        print("Incorrect answer.")
        print(f"{q} does not equal {a}")
    print()

print(f"{correct} out of {len(test)} questions were answered correctly.")
```

#### Output

```
You answered correctly!
Question 1 does equal True

Incorrect answer.
Question 2 does not equal False

You answered correctly!
Question 3 does equal True

2 out of 3 questions were answered correctly.
```